# is .net faster than java

Tags: c#, java, .net, performance, jakarta-ee

I heard a lot of people saying that java is slow comparing .net, like they had servers with application on java with jboss hibernate and other stuff and it was really slow, but when they moved to .net all the performance issues disappeared. Is java really much slower ?
isthere any benchmarks made ?

Comment: Subjective based on the nature of the application and skill of the programmer.

Comment: At the very least this should be a community wiki.

Comment: "when they moved to .net" you can't just magically move to .NET - it requires a rewrite, which nearly always results in major improvements as a natural byproduct.

Comment: Yes. No. I think that pretty much covers the topic.

Comment: Short answer generalization, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is going to get closed as flame-bait, but I'll make a comment, anyway.

In my experience, Java servers/services can be just as performant as .Net servers/services.  It depends more on the skill and experience of the designer & developer than the technology.

That being said, it is also my experience that *most* Java-based desktop applications (with significant user interfaces) are horribly slow and tend to exhibit weird behavioral issues.  While it's possible for an inexperienced or unskilled C# developer to create the same bad UI in .Net, it is *much* more unlikely that a competent C# developer will experience these types of issues when writing a .Net app, compared to a similarly competent Java developer putting similar functionality into a Java app.